# Is the auto load-balancing enabled by the cluster mode in PM2 active when using AMQP?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

The PM2 process manager allows to launch nodejs processes in the `fork` and `cluster` modes.

I understand that the `cluster` mode allows to launch `n` processes where `n` is the number of cores in the machine. *http,tcp or udp* load is then automatically balanced between these processes.

I am wondering if this load balancing is also occurring for AMQP messaging traffic.

I have a bunch (around 10) of JavaScript scripts that consume message via *RabbitMQ* (which implements the amqp protocol), these scripts are launched by PM2 in `cluster` mode in a 4 core machine which brings us to 4 instances per script.

Is the cluster mode making any difference in the previous scenario?

**Is there some form of load balancing taking place when using RabbitMQ?**